# Calculate the limit of integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm doing exercises in Real Analysis of Folland and got stuck on this problem. I don't know how to calculate limit with the variable on the upper bound of the integral. Hope some one can help me solve this. I really appreciate.

> > Show that $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^kx^n(1-k^{-1}x)^k~dx=n!$

Thanks so much for your consideration.

Comment: Make the substitution $u=x/k$.

Comment: I think if you integrate by parts, keeping $x^n$ the second function, and go on recursively, $n!$ term should pop out. And then you can take limit $k \rightarrow \infty$ the remaining factor could be 1 ? Have you tried this way ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have

$$\int_0^k x^n(1-k^{-1}x)^kdx=\int_0^\infty x^n(1-k^{-1}x)^k\chi_{(0,k)}dx$$
then since
$$x^n(1-k^{-1}x)^k\chi_{(0,k)}\le x^n e^{-x},\;\forall k$$
and the function
$$x\mapsto x^n e^{-x}$$ is integrable on the interval $(0,\infty)$ then by the dominated convergence theorem we have
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^k x^n(1-k^{-1}x)^kdx=\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx=\Gamma(n+1)=n!$$

Comment: absolutely right. Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
f_k(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\left(1-\frac{x}{k}\right)^{k}x^n & \text{if} & x\in [0,k], \\ \\
0 & \text{if} & x>k.
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Then
$$
0\le f_k(x)\le \mathrm{e}^{-x}x^n,
$$
for all $k$ and $x\ge 0$, and $\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-x}x^n$, for all $x\ge 0$.

[Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) is applicable as $\mathrm{e}^{-x}x^n\in L^1(0,\infty)$, and implies that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^k \left(1-\frac{x}{k}\right)^k x^n\,dx=
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^\infty f_k(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x}\,x^n\,dx=\Gamma(n+1)=n!
$$

Comment: correctly. thanks so much...

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Hereafter we'll use the [Beta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$\ds{{\rm B}\pars{x,y} = \int_{0}^{1}t^{x - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{y - 1}\,\dd t}$ 
with $\ds{\pars{~\Re\pars{x} > 0\,,\Re\pars{y} > 0~}}$ and its property
$\ds{{\rm B}\pars{x,y} = {\Gamma\pars{x}\Gamma\pars{y} \over \Gamma\pars{x + y}}}$.
$\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the [Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). For $n\ \in\ {\mathbb N}$, it
satisfies $\ds{\Gamma\pars{n + 1} = n!}$.

> \begin{align}
> &\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{0}^{k}x^{n}\pars{1 -k^{- 1}x}^{k}\,\dd x=
> \lim_{k \to \infty}\bracks{k^{n + 1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\pars{1 - x}^{k}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{k \to \infty}\bracks{k^{n + 1}{\rm B}\pars{n + 1,k + 1}}
> =\lim_{k \to \infty}\bracks{%
> k^{n + 1}\,{\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{k + 1}\over \Gamma\pars{n + k + 2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=n!\lim_{k \to \infty}\bracks{{k^{n + 1}k! \over \pars{n + k + 1}!}}
> \tag{1}
> \end{align}

However,
\begin{align}
&\lim_{k \to \infty}\bracks{k^{n + 1}k! \over \pars{n + k + 1}!}
=\lim_{k \to \infty}
\bracks{k^{n + 1} \over \pars{k + n + 1}\pars{k + n}\ldots\pars{k + 1}}
\\[3mm]&=
\lim_{k \to \infty}\bracks{%
\pars{1 + {n + 1 \over k}}\pars{1 + {n \over k}}\ldots\pars{1 + {1 \over k}}}^{-1}
= 1
\end{align}

> By replacing this result in $\pars{1}$, we get:
>   $$\color{#00f}{\large%
> \lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{0}^{k}x^{n}\pars{1 -k^{- 1}x}^{k}\,\dd x
> =n!}
> $$

Comment: Yes, this is the painful approach: more complicated, more error-prone, fails as soon as one perturbs the problem, does not explain why the result holds.